# RSpec proper way to check created column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I've got POST endpoint which creates a new `JourneyProgress` record in my db.

```
    post :enroll do
      JourneyProgress.create!(user: current_user, journey: journey, percent_progress: 0.0, started_at: DateTime.now)
      status :no_content
    end
```

I want to check if `percent_progress` and `started_at` were set with below example:

```
  let(:current_date) { 'Thu, 16 Jul 2020 17:08:02 +0200'.to_date }

  before do
    allow(DateTime).to receive(:now) { current_date }
  end

    it 'set starting progress' do
      call
      expect(JourneyProgress.last.started_at).to eq(current_date)
      expect(JourneyProgress.last.percent_progress).to eq(0.0)
    end
```

The specs will pass but I'm not sure if `JourneyProgress.last.(some record name)` is in line with convention. Is there a better way to check this?

If I change it to:

```
it 'set starting progress' do
  expect(call.started_at).to eq(current_date)
  ...
end
```

I'm getting an error:

```
 NoMethodError:
   undefined method `started_at' for 204:Integer
```

Comment: Your endpoint returns ``status :no_content`` (HTTP 204), which is why you get the error in the second usage. So, if you care about checking the values of the new record you will need to look it up as you have (or simply check that the count of  ``JourneyProgress`` records increased by 1).

Comment: The correct status code would be 201 Created and either include a  location header with the newly created resource or a JSON response body containing the resource. A 204 response is just useless to the client in this case.

Comment: I would say it's better to check the HTTP response but this approach works alright too.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to test the value of the `started_at` column, something like this would work.

```
it 'set starting progress' do
  call
  expect(JourneyProgress.last.started_at).to eq(current_date)
end
```

but I'd suggest that you think twice about what is worth testing in this scenario, it would make a lot more sense to check that a `JourneyProgress` record is being inserted into your DB and that the endpoint actually returns the correct HTTP Status code.

```
  it 'persists the record in database' do
    expect { call }.to change { JourneyProgress.count }.by(1)
  end

  it 'responds with no content status' do
    call
    expect(response).to have_http_status(:no_content)
  end
```

As other comments state I'd also use [201 (created)](https://httpstatuses.com/201#:%7E:text=%C3%97%C3%97%20Success-,201%20Created,by%20the%20effective%20request%20URI.) instead of no content in this context.

Comment: Do you really need to test ActiveRecord?

Comment: @aridlehoover more than testing ActiveRecord you are testing that your endpoint is persisting something to the database so if in the future somebody mistakenly changes the `.create` part for something else, the test would break.

Comment: Somehow, I missed the fact that this was a controller test. By all means, go ahead and hit the database. That's the Rails way.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to write an integration test that verifies that your software wrote a record to the database with the appropriate values for percent_progress and started_at.

You are correct to be concerned about using `.last` in your tests like you have. If you were to run your tests in parallel on a build server, there's a good chance that two different tests would both be adding records to the database at the same time (or in an indeterminate order), causing the test to be flaky. You could resolve this potential flakiness by returning the id of the newly created record and then looking up that record in the test after the call event. But, there's a better solution...

If you were to modify your migration for the JourneyProgress model to look like this:

```
create_table :journey_progress do |t|
  t.user_id :integer
  t.journey_id :integer
  t.percent_progress :float, default: 0.0

  t.timestamps
end
```

Then, you would be guaranteed that the `percent_progress` field would always default to `0.0`. And, you could use the ActiveRecord managed `created_at` timestamp in lieu of the custom `started_at` timestamp that you would have to manage.

So, you won't have to test that either thing got set correctly, because you can trust ActiveRecord and your database to do the right thing because they've already been thoroughly tested by their authors.

Now, your code would look more like this:

```
post :enroll do
  journey_progress = JourneyProgress.create!(
    user: current_user, 
    journey: journey
  )

  status :created
end
```

And, your tests would look more like what Sebastian Delgado mentioned:

```
it 'persists the record in database' do
  expect { call }.to change { JourneyProgress.count }.by(1)
end
```